# What model to use to predict rare occurances? For example, when someone takes medicine

Tags: python, data-mining, prediction

I've tried to build a prediction model that would give me a probability of a person taking medicine given certain conditions. What I'm most interested about is that the model would relatively accurately be able to predict when someone takes medicine. I have a dataframe that has 1400 rows, where about 134 rows are those where the user takes medicine. I have a df that looks somewhat like the example below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time_hour': ['6', '12', '18'], 
               'weekday': [6, 1, 3],
               'previous_action': ['eat', 'sleep', 'eat'],
               'take_medicine': [0, 1, 1]})
```

I've tried solving this with logistic regression and bernoulli naive bayes, but each of them only bet on the most common outcome, which is the person not taking medicine. I've tried googling how to solve this without success.

I've looked at the data and the person takes medicine daily at 12 and 18, so I'm curious why the results are so bad. Is there another model that would suit this kind of problem better or should I be doing something differently?

Here is an example what I've done previously

```
predictors = ['time_hour', 'weekday', 'previous_action']
X = df[predictors]
y = df['take_medicine']
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=0)

from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
bert = BernoulliNB()
bert.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = bert.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

Which returns

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Predicting rare occurrences is called **anomaly detection**, you can look it up, there are many models that might be useful in your case such as **isolation forest** that is present in the `sklearn` library.